# Access to XMLHttpRequest header problem in react and node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, axios, cors

in my code my backend it running on port 4000 and my frontend on port 3000
when axios get the data i have this error on console on web
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:4000/api/v1/me' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

i have installed cors on backend and this is my server.js

```
const app = require("./app");
const cloudinary = require("cloudinary");
const connectDatabase = require("./config/database");
const cors = require('cors');

// Config
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "PRODUCTION") {
    require("dotenv").config({ path: "backend/config/config.env" });
}

// Connecting to database
connectDatabase();

// Adding CORS middleware

app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    methods: 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE',
    headers: 'Content-Type, Authorization',
    credentials: true
}));
// cloudinary.config({
//     cloud_name: process.env.CLOUDINARY_NAME,
//     api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY,
//     api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET,
// });

const server = app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is working on http://localhost:${process.env.PORT}`);
});

// Handling Uncaught Exception
process.on("uncaughtException", (err) => {
    console.log(`Error: ${err.message}`);
    console.log(`Shutting down the server due to Uncaught Exception`);
    process.exit(1);
});

// Unhandled Promise Rejection
process.on("unhandledRejection", (err) => {
    console.log(`Error: ${err.message}`);
    console.log(`Shutting down the server due to Unhandled Promise Rejection`);

    server.close(() => {
        process.exit(1);
    });
});
```

and this is a part of my axios api

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
export const getProduct =
    (keyword = "", currentPage = 1, price = [0, 25000], category, ratings = 0) =>
    async(dispatch) => {
        try {
            dispatch({ type: ALL_PRODUCT_REQUEST });

            let link = `http://localhost:4000/api/v1/products?keyword=${keyword}&page=${currentPage}&price[gte]=${price[0]}&price[lte]=${price[1]}&ratings[gte]=${ratings}`;

            if (category) {
                link = `http://localhost:4000/api/v1/products?keyword=${keyword}&page=${currentPage}&price[gte]=${price[0]}&price[lte]=${price[1]}&category=${category}&ratings[gte]=${ratings}`;
            }

            const { data } = await axios.get(link);

            dispatch({
                type: ALL_PRODUCT_SUCCESS,
                payload: data,
            });
        } catch (error) {
            dispatch({
                type: ALL_PRODUCT_FAIL,
                payload: error.response.data.message,
            });
        }
    };
```

anyone can help me to solve this?